# quay.io/etcd Container Command not found

Tags: docker, coreos, etcd

I am getting following error:

> docker: Error response from daemon: Container command '-name' not
>   found or does not exist.

I am following the example in [the CoreOS documentation for running etcd under Docker](https://coreos.com/etcd/docs/latest/docker_guide.html).

The following is the configuration I am trying to run:

```
docker run -d -v /usr/share/ca-certificates/:/etc/ssl/certs -p 4001:4001 -p 2380:2380 -p 2379:2379 \
 --name etcd quay.io/coreos/etcd \
 -name k8_etcd0 \
 -advertise-client-urls http://10.0.0.4:2379,http://10.0.0.3:4001 \
 -listen-client-urls http://0.0.0.0:2379,http://0.0.0.0:4001 \
 -initial-advertise-peer-urls http://10.0.0.3:2380 \
 -listen-peer-urls http://0.0.0.0:2380 \
 -initial-cluster-token etcd-cluster-1 \
 -initial-cluster k8_etcd0=http://10.0.0.4,k8_etcd1=http://10.0.0.5:2388 \
 -initial-cluster-state new
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're missing command to launch in your docker container `etcd`

```
docker run -d -v /usr/share/ca-certificates/:/etc/ssl/certs -p 4001:4001 -p 2380:2380 -p 2379:2379 \
 --name etcd quay.io/coreos/etcd \
 etcd \
 -name k8_etcd0 \
 -advertise-client-urls http://10.0.0.4:2379,http://10.0.0.3:4001 \
 -listen-client-urls http://0.0.0.0:2379,http://0.0.0.0:4001 \
 -initial-advertise-peer-urls http://10.0.0.3:2380 \
 -listen-peer-urls http://0.0.0.0:2380 \
 -initial-cluster-token etcd-cluster-1 \
 -initial-cluster k8_etcd0=http://10.0.0.4,k8_etcd1=http://10.0.0.5:2388 \
 -initial-cluster-state new
```

plus some fixes that you need about initial cluster etc. but that you will see when you launch it in error messages

Comment: Thanks it works, but have errors messages like you said.

Answer (score -1):

You have two errors in your docker run command - 
1. you've specified the `name` flag twice
2. On the second time you've specified it, you've used a single dash instead of a double dash, as you should.

So the solution would be to delete the second name flag, and then your command should look like this -

```
docker run -d -v /usr/share/ca-certificates/:/etc/ssl/certs -p 4001:4001 -p 2380:2380 -p 2379:2379 \
 --name etcd quay.io/coreos/etcd \
 -advertise-client-urls http://10.0.0.4:2379,http://10.0.0.3:4001 \
 -listen-client-urls http://0.0.0.0:2379,http://0.0.0.0:4001 \
 -initial-advertise-peer-urls http://10.0.0.3:2380 \
 -listen-peer-urls http://0.0.0.0:2380 \
 -initial-cluster-token etcd-cluster-1 \
 -initial-cluster k8_etcd0=http://10.0.0.4,k8_etcd1=http://10.0.0.5:2388 \
 -initial-cluster-state new
```

I tried running it locally to see if works after the fix I've suggested, but got an error since the ips specified in the command are unknown to my computer. If they make sense inside your setup - the command should work after applying my fixes.

Comment: in fact, one name is a docker container name, and the other is etcd internal name for this node in cluster

Comment: Right you are, I missed that. Thanks for that.